# Is there a way to tweak AVPlayer so that scrubbing backward/reverse is as fast as forward scrubbing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avplayer

If I create an `AVPlayerLayer` and give it a remote video to stream, and include a `UISlider` for scrubbing the video to different points, scrubbing forward is very precise and smooth. Super great.

Scrubbing backward however is very choppy and unreliable with a lot of dropped frames.

Is there a way to prevent this at all? I'm guessing `AVPlayer` is aggressive about removing already-watched portions of a video and the buffer is simply being reduced, but I'm curious if there's a way to curb this behaviour.

The same can be seen when putting `rate` to -1 instead of 1, where with 1 it plays smoothly and -1 is choppy.

Comment: This has more to do with keyframes. Frames are composited forward from the keyframe in both play mode and fast forward. However when rewinding all the decoder has to go on is each keyframe therefore it stutters. This is just the nature of how it is encoded. As @Karim suggests below, the only effective way of dealing with this would be to actually write the stuff to disk as you stream it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest downloading the file to disk then playing it using AVPlayer

> some code might help